# What's the meaning of "line up"?

Tags: meaning

This is a quote from [cracked.com](http://www.cracked.com/article_19303_6-reasons-professional-poker-way-harder-than-it-looks.html):

> It's a long, grinding game(poker) of patience and attrition. And that's because it's all about tediously waiting for the percentages to **line up** in your favor -- successful poker players only play about 20 percent of the hands they're dealt. That's right -- 80 percent of the time, they're spectators.

What does *line up* mean in this context? My feeling is that it could mean "to become", like waiting for the percentages to become in your favour.

This is a definition I found on Merriam Learners Dictionary that I think could fit as well:

> 4.
>   line (something) up or line up (something) : to succeed in getting (something)
>     - He has been trying to line up support for his proposal.
>     - She managed to line up a summer job.

Comment: It's a reference to slot machines where you win when each of the spinning wheels in the machine slow down and stop such that the same image is displayed on each-  i.e., the images are all in a line.  http://media.salon.com/2013/07/shutterstock_100557667.jpg

Comment: ...or lined up like celestial bodies in [syzygy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syzygy_(astronomy))?

Comment: there's utterly no connection to a slot machine "line" per se.  it's a completely common phrase that any native English speaker would know.  "we're waiting until all the ducks are in a line" is another variant.

Comment: @JoeBlow - The expression may not originate with slot machines, but it's the ideal illustration of the concept.

Comment: Hi Hot .. possibly, but it's such an extremely commonplace phrase in English ("let's get this paperwork lined up" "everything was lined up for the business") it's almost like, "illustrating" it in any particular way can introduce some confusion.  There are bound to be English learners who read this page, and go away thinking it has something to do with slot machines, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means "to fall in to their favour" .. "to becone arranged in their favour".

it's not unlike saying "we'll wait for the stars to align" (you've heard this phrase right?) or "we'll wait until everything falls in to line" or "we'll wait until everything's right for us to proceed" or "we'll wait until conditions are right".

There's nothing more to it than that.

(The Merriam reference is utterly useless - forget it.)

Answer (score 5):

Looking at 6 possible meanings of the phrasal verb *[line up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/line+up)*:

> v.
>
> 1. To form a line:
>    *The students lined up at the front of the classroom.
>
>    People are lining up to get tickets to the game.*
> 2. To arrange some people or things in a line:
>    *The police lined the suspects up against the wall.
>
>    We lined up some chairs in front of the stage.
>
>    Customers were lined up waiting for the stores to open.*
> 3. To organize something or someone for an event or activity; schedule something or someone:
>    *I've lined two interviews up for next week.
>
>    The organizers lined up some great speakers for the rally.
>
>    The senator is lining up support for the bill.*
> 4. To straighten something, or put it in the correct position in relation to some other thing:
>    *I lined the text up with the edge of the page.
>
>    The sniper lined up the rifle and fired two shots at the middle of the target.
>
>    We lined up the holes and put the bolt through.*
> 5. To be straight or in the correct position in relation to some other thing:
>    *The holes don't line up—I can't get the bolt in.
>
>    Does this painting line up with the ceiling?*
> 6. In American football, to take one's position in a formation before a snap or kickoff:
>    *The players lined up at the scrimmage line.*
>
> *The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs.*

Since percentages don't get in line literally, definitions 1 & 2 are excluded. Since percentages aren't football players, definition 6 is excluded. Definition 5 seems to be the closest choice for a metaphorical application to percentages:

> ...it's all about tediously waiting for the percentages to be [**in a favorable position**].

That is: it is all about tediously waiting for a hand of cards worth betting on.